# Cannot add TLSharp to PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, telegram

I am trying to add Telegram support to my Xamarin.Forms App.

The only thing I found is [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp), which looks great but I'm not able to add it to my PCL. I also tried to download the whole code and add/copy the contents to a PCL and tried fixing the issues appearing to me but with no success.

The main problem is that I cannot add TLSharp to my PCL is because of DotNetZip 1.9.3 which obviously has currently no PCL support. But I issued a new pull request for that on GitHub.

```
Could not install package 'DotNetZip 1.9.3'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

So I tried to create a new PCL and copy the contents from TLSharp step by step.

This is my progress so far. The `TLSharp.Core` looks like this:

[image]

We know that `DontNetZib` is incompatible but that's okay so far (pull request open and I may use another zipping DLL?!)

But I cannot get any further than this:

[image]

Where are all my common `.dlls` gone ? 
I know in PCL some assemblies are added during the build but how about XML and stuff? I cannot add any of them via RightClick on References => add Reference.

Comment: any advice/remark or just a close+downvote ?

Comment: you can write your own implementation for telegram API using just portable class libs if you want. search SO for help on getting started.

Comment: What are the issues you're hitting? What have you tried to fix them?

Comment: Perhaps instead of adding it to the PCL add it to your platform projects and use a Dependency Service [1] to access TLSharp from your PCl code. [1] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Comment: @jgoldberger sadly this is not working either